# Why does this syntax outputs an error under METAFUN/METAPOST?

Tags: metapost, metafun

Given this MWE (compiled under ConTeXt)

```
\starttext
\startMPpage

%variables
u:=1mm ;
numeric l[];
l[1]:=30 ;
l[2]:=70 ;

draw (0,0) -- (0,100u) ;
%this does not work
%fill unitsquare xscaled (l[2]-l[1])*u yscaled 100*u shifted (l[1]*u,0) withcolor red ;

%this does
fill unitsquare xscaled (l[2]*u-l[1]*u) yscaled 100u shifted (l[1]*u,0) withcolor red ;

\stopMPpage
\stoptext
```

Could you explain me why

```
fill unitsquare xscaled (l[2]-l[1])*u yscaled 100*u shifted (l[1]*u,0) withcolor red ;
```

fails, whereas

```
fill unitsquare xscaled (l[2]*u-l[1]*u) yscaled 100*u shifted (l[1]*u,0) withcolor red ;
```

does the job?

From my (not so good in maths) points of view, (l[2]-l[1])*u should be exactly the same, and this misunderstandings leads me often to frustrating errors.

I hope this is not a duplicate, but didn't know how to produce a proper title.

Comment: Have you tried `xscaled ((l[2]-l[1])*u)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the Metapost manual, `xscaled` is a *primary*, so it has the same priority as multiplication.

It takes as arguments a pair, path or picture and a number, returning a pair, path or picture respectively; with your “non working” syntax Metapost is doing

```
unitsquare xscaled (l[2]-l[1])
```

and then trying to multiply the result by `u`, which is an invalid operation.

When operations have the same priority (all primaries, for instance), Metapost associates on the left. To get a different association you need parentheses.

The error you get is

```
>> path
>> 2.83464
! Not implemented: (path)*(known numeric).
<to be read again> 
                   yscaled
```

Of course `((l[2]-l[1])*u)` would work as well, but the outer parentheses cannot be omitted.